# IllegalStateException fragment did not create a view after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, orientation-changes

I have an app that has a main activity that the user can select an item from. That selection brings up a fragment (`TracksActivityFragment`) that itself is another list. When an item of that list is selected, a fragment is added that is a `DialogFragment`. So far so good, but when I rotate the device, the AFragment's `onCreate()` gets called and then the `DailogFragment's` `onCreate()` gets called, then it dies with the `IllegalStateException` saying that it dies on `AFragment's` Activity line 20 (`setContentView`).

Here is a part of that Activity with the line in question:

```
public class TracksActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private String mArtistName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tracks); //DIES HERE
```

Here is the onCreate of the fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        //We've got data saved. Reconstitute it
        mTrackRowItemList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(KEY_ITEMS_LIST);
    }
}
```

The `DialogFragment` gets created in the `TracksFragment` like this:

```
PlayerFragment fragment = PlayerFragment.newInstance(mTrackRowItemList, i, mArtistBitmapFilename);

// The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();

// For a little polish, specify a transition animation
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

// To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
// for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here is the DialogFragment's onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        //We've got data saved. Reconstitute it
        if (mPlayer != null)
        {
            mPlayer.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SONG_POSITION));
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why it goes back to the `TracksFragment` since it had the `DialogFragment` active on rotation, but since that is the case, it would seem like I would need to recreate the entire`DialogPlayer` object, But it seems to keep this around as the call to its `onCreate` happens.

Anyone know what it is that needs to be done here?

Answer (score 3):

OK, this was asked before but I discounted the solution...I should not have.

For some reason, Android wants the Tracks layout XML to use a FrameLayout instead of a fragment.

So, just replace fragment with FrameLayout in the layout xml file and all is well.

Comment: What is it that `FrameLayout` replaced? Can you post the original layout to the question?

Comment: I didn't replace fragment with FrameLayout, I just wrapped the fragment in a FrameLayout and that fixed the screen orientation change exception. I don't think I'd ever have guessed that was the cause, the exception message is next to useless in this case.

Comment: I just replace in main layout xml,  the word " <Fragment "  with <FrameLayout,  and works like a charm, thanks, and SO

Comment: This definitely solved my problem. This should accept this as the answer. Perhaps with a link to documentation (if you can find it) about WHY this is the case.